# angular 5 extend component from shared project

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular5

here is project structure

[image]

I want my Component on Project X "header.Component.ts" extend from my "header.Component.ts" project sheredComponent.

tanks

Comment: StackOverflow is not the place to get the solution done by placing the requirement. This is neither a question nor problem. Show us what have tried so far or this question may sink.

Comment: i'm working on a refactor i have 2 project_x and project_x the code is duplicate on 2 project i want to sort the duplicated component into a paratged project

Comment: What's the intention behind extending project header from shared header? Can't you just have a single header in shared and if project specific changes are required in the header, pass those as @Input properties?